# Search within same ID across several rows

Tags: mysql, select

My table has the following structure:

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
| id | word_id | meaning_id | sentence_id |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
| 1  | 1       | 15333      | 1           |
| 2  | 1       | 12355      | 1           |
| 3  | 1       | 768        | 1           |
| 4  | 2       | 12455      | 1           |
| 5  | 2       | 9581       | 1           |
| 6  | 3       | 41         | 1           |
| 7  | 4       | 125        | 1           |
| 8  | 1       | 17854      | 2           |
| 9  | 2       | 35214      | 2           |
| 10 | 3       | 12455      | 2           |
| 11 | 3       | 988        | 2           |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
```

I have a list of `meaning_ids` and I want to get all the `sentence_ids` that contain **all** of the `meaning_ids`. I do not care what the sentence it is, as long as the sentence contains all `meaning_ids` (= `sentence_id` is the same).

Lets say I have the following sentence_ids: 12455 and 15333. The query should return `sentence_id` 1 because both only occur there.

How can I achieve this with MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requirement is known as [relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). One popular approach is

```
SELECT sentence_id
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  meaning_id IN ( 12455, 15333 )
GROUP  BY sentence_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT meaning_id) = 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dd0c/1)

If your table has a unique constraint on `sentence_id,meaning_id` you can drop the `DISTINCT` in the query above.

Comment: See also this similar question at SO which has more than 10 different ways (some will not work in mysql) to achieve relational division: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)