# What is the correct SQL for using where ID in List and the items are with AND operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a SQL Statement to use IN operator within the items with "And" connected.

```
SELECT * from tbl_Users
WHERE id in [1,2,3]
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * from tbl_Users
WHERE (id=1) or (id = 2) or (id = 3)
```

What I need is to generate using IN operator (or equivalent):

```
SELECT * from tbl_Users
WHERE (id=1) AND (id = 2) AND (id = 3)
```

Because I collect all the IDs (ex: [1,2,3,4,5]) in one string and search with it in the DB.

***More Explanation:***

ID is always a primary key

The case is I have a table which has all countries, and each country has several electrical standards in separate table.

Example: 
Germany requires always "standard1" and "standard2"
USA required always "Standard1" and "standard3"
France required always "Standard2"

If the user in C# application search for a country which has "Standard2", the system should give him Germany and France.

**BUT** If the user wants countries with "Standard1" **AND** "standard2", the system should only give him Germany.  -> because of "AND"

My Query was

```
Select  * from [tables and joins]
where STANDARD_id IN [1,2]
```

[1,2] is a concatenated list which the user already choose from a list of standards.

Comment: If `id` is the primary key then `WHERE (id=1) AND (id = 2) AND (id = 3)` will return 0 rows. Always.

Comment: If `id` is not the primary or unique key, then you probably want relational division. Which is the case?

Comment: Even if `id` is not unique, it can only be `1` **OR** `2` **OR** `3` on any single row.

Comment: And, assuming the problem can be restated somehow, why build a string of characters when the `id` list could be temporarily stored in a `table`, `#temptable` or `@tablevariable` thus avoiding the string concatenation followed by a split function.

Comment: Are you saying that 1) the `ID` field is a string that contains the value `[1,2,3,4,5]` and 2) you want to pass in `1,2,3` to see if it matches that string value? If not, then why do you want an AND? You should update the question with the datatype of the `ID` field and a few sample values.

Comment: I guess now we can close it as duplicate of: [Search within same ID accross several rows](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36866/search-within-same-id-accross-several-rows)

Comment: Or maybe this one, which has more ways to do it and a title that resembles the title here: [Make IN clause behave like AND clause](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74643/make-in-clause-behave-like-and-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is **relational division**. Here is the best explanation I could find

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Honestly I do not fully understand this myself yet, but I believe this should work (using an intermediate table):

```
CREATE TABLE tblCountry (
    countryId int,
    countryName nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO tblCountry
    SELECT 1, 'Germany' UNION
    SELECT 2, 'United States' UNION
    SELECT 3, 'France'

CREATE TABLE tblStandards (
    standardId int,
    standardName nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO tblStandards
    SELECT 1, 'standard_1' UNION
    SELECT 2, 'standard_2' UNION
    SELECT 3, 'standard_3'

CREATE TABLE tblCountryStandards (
    countryId int,
    standardId int
)

INSERT INTO tblCountryStandards
    SELECT 1, 1 UNION
    SELECT 1, 2 UNION
    SELECT 2, 1 UNION
    SELECT 2, 3 UNION
    SELECT 3, 2

SELECT countryName
FROM tblCountry
    INNER JOIN tblCountryStandards ON tblCountry.countryId = tblCountryStandards.countryId
    INNER JOIN tblStandards ON tblStandards.standardId = tblCountryStandards.standardId
WHERE tblStandards.standardId IN (1, 2) -- unique standards selected by user
GROUP BY tblCountry.countryName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tblStandards.standardId) = 2 -- number of standards selected by user above
```

This is based on your example, but I tested more combinations and it works if the commented values are changed.

There are many other ways of doing the division explained in the link provided above - you should use the one that suits your purposes best.